# Implementing a google map fragment to an activity

Tags: android

I am having a hard time implementing my google map fragment into an activity and from everything else I'me reading I'm getting more confused.

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

This section crashes my app gives me the error must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener. Which I find confusing since I thought that since it was part of the throw it would prevent the app from crashing regardless of if the error was there. 
In my main method I have 
 `private void addMapFragment(){
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.mapView, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }`

Which is called in the onCreate method. Honestly I just don't exactly where to look. I feel like I have something somewhere else causing the crash but I cant figure out what it is. So I don't know if this is relevant but here is the code that also exists in the same file as the onStart method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume();

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    //Latitude and longitude ????
    double latitude = 17.385044;
    double longitude = 78.486671;

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");


    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


    return v;
}
```

Comment: The crash is caused because your activity does not implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. You are catching the exception, but you throw it again in the `onStart` method. If you are not using `mListener` remove the code in the onStart method, or just make your activity implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Comment: Ugg I feel so dumb now. But I'm new. Implementing the listener worked great. Thanks dawg.